# BASH: date expects 12 hour by default, input is in 24 hour

Tags: linux, date

I have a simple question here.

I have an input date with time of 05:21, but it could be any arbitrary 24 hour time. 
I add 1 minute to it using the date command. date then outputs 17:22!!

I need the output format to be 24 hour because that's what the input format is, and what is required.

How do I tell date to stop messing with the times?

I'm very close to just using substr to extract the minutes, and then adding 1, and then adding a check to see if >59 and if so, value = 0 and substr the hour value out, then add 1 to that, because at this point it seems simpler.

```
end='12-02-2018 17:01'
test=$(echo $end | sed -re 's#(..)-(..)-(....) (..:..)()#\3-\2-\1 \4#') ; 
add=$(date +"%d-%m-%Y %H:%M" --date="$test + 1 minute") ; 
echo $test --- $add
2018-02-12 17:01 --- 13-02-2018 05:02
```

Comment: could you add your code please?

Comment: Does this behavior occurs with `LANG=C date ...` And put the date command in your post (and your country/locale)

Comment: What are you doing to get your output? e.g. `date -d "5:21"` results in `Tue Feb 20 05:21:00 CST 2018` and `date -d "5:22"` results in `Tue Feb 20 05:22:00 CST 2018`. What are you doing different?

Comment: Added code, hopefully that makes it clearer.  
I've also just noticed that it doesn't add 1 minute- it adds 12 hours and 1 minute.